# Angular 2/4 dynamic styling

Tags: jquery, angular

how do i write this in angular 2/4?

```
  $('nav ul li a').click(function(){  
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  });
```

Comment: even this code will work in angular2/4 , without any problem, is there any problem running this code with angular2 ?

Comment: i referenced jquery and master.js in index.html and, run the applicaiton. 
and clicked a - nothing happened.. i did console.log('mahesh'), 
can't see mahesh in console.

Comment: could you post your full code on plunker ?, ill fix it

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can add css class dynamically for example see here

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let menu of navMenu'>
        <a (click)='Styling(menu)' [class.active]='menu?.active'>hello {{menu?.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

Styling(menu){
    for(let i=0; i< this.navMenu.length; i++){
      this.navMenu[i].active = false;
    }
    menu.active = true;
  }
```

## **<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKeVKgH3Hi8MYbcdin80?p=preview)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You should use property binding

```
<nav>
    <ul> 
        <li> 
            <a [class.active]="active"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You should have the following in component

```
active:boolean =false
```

Comment: if i did this way, i have to put [class.active] in my every a, 
how can i avoid doing that???

Comment: you can have the class in the common stylesheet. What is the actual purpose of this?